# Consecutive numbers in array list using boolean expressions

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble executing this function in which it would print out "true" if there is 2 consecutive numbers in an array and "false"if not. The errors I get is that a boolean cannot be converted to an int and also in the last line of code what would I have to put inside the brackets for System.out.println()?

```
public class A1Q2 {
    private static int hasTwoLengthRun(int[] array) { 
        for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++){
            if(array[i+1] == array[i]){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int[] array = new int[]{5, 16, 7, 35, -2, -9, 75};
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: You declared your function to return `int`, but you `return true` which is not an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)`hasTwoLengthRun()` should return a `boolean` and not an `int` as you return `boolean` values.

2) it has a broken logic as it returns `false` as soon as two elements of the array are not equals between.
 You should return `false` only when you have iterated over all elements.

3) For the compiler the method doesn't return a value since you return a value only in the `for`. If you have a array with no element, you don't enter in the `for` and you return nothing. It is not legal.

4) you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` with the `for` condition as the last iteration use a index out of the array.

Here is a code that should work :

```
private static boolean hasTwoLengthRun(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        if (array[i + 1] == array[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see at least 3 problems here:

1. Return type of `hasTwoLengthRun` function should be `boolean`
2. You've incorrectly arranged `return false` statement - it should be invocated in the end of the method
3. You've incorrectly used array boundaries - you'll get exception trying to reach element out of array.

Here is the corrected code:

```
public class Test {
    private static boolean hasTwoLengthRun(int[] array) {

        for(int i=0; i < array.length - 1; i++){
            if(array[i+1] == array[i]){
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[]{5, 16, 7, 35, -2, -9, 75};
        System.out.println(hasTwoLengthRun(array));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an error, because you've written that your `hasTwoLengthRun` function returns `int`, while in your `return` statements you return `true` or `false` - a `boolean`-typed values.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
private static int hasTwoLengthRun(...
```

says the method shall return an int. A number.

Then you return true/false. In java, those two types can **not** be interchanged.

So, change to:

```
private static boolean hasTwoLengthRun(...
```

Besides; your logic is wrong:

```
for(int i=0; i < array.length-1; i++){
  if(array[i+1] == array[i]) {
    return true;
  }
}
return false;
```

is what you need instead; to A) avoid running **over** the length of your array and B) not returning with false when the first two elements are not matching your condition!